# passing data from Parent component to Grandchild component throw child component (React JS)

Tags: reactjs

How can I pass data from parent component to grandchild component through child component? Can I useEffect()? Any leads, please?

***NOTE*** :I'm using functional Components lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Use ContextAPI.
You can pass data from parent to child using ContextAPI